# Batch - check if null session connection exist

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking

I have this shared location mapped to **NO** local drive. How can I check if it exist, ideally I want the query to return a true or false. 
**Example**: `IF EXIST \\\pc-name.domain.net ECHO true` `SYNTAGM` doesn't detect the mapped location.

Output of `NET USE`:

```
Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK                     \\pc-name.domain.net\IPC$
                                                Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: `for` and `findstr`.

Comment: `IF EXIST` only detects the existence of a file or a drive.

Comment: Define 'check if null session connection exist'. This is just gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

This will probably help:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3" %%G IN ('net use^| Find "\\"') DO (
  echo %%H exists
)
```

Where you can set Find to what you need. This specific instance will search for anything mapped where the below will purely search for `IPC$`

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3" %%G IN ('net use^| Find "IPC$"') DO (
  echo %%H exists
)
```

Comment: `tokens=1,2,3` can be shortened to `tokens=1-3`

Comment: The solution provided by Gerhard returns an error: "find: unable to access "IPC$": The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: How about `findstr /c:"IPC$"` instead of `Find "IPC$"`?

Comment: SteveFest your solution is working" FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3" %%G IN ('net use^| findstr /c:"IPC$"') DO (
  echo %%H exists
) Thank you guys !!